# Reference last element of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my code, I have a lot code like this:

```
my_array[my_array.length - 1] = sth;
```

Is it possible to define a simple variable to point to last element of array?like this:

```
var ref =  (&|*, sth like that) my_array[my_array.length - 1];
ref = sth;
```

Comment: is your goal to replace the last element of an array?

Comment: Yes, a lot of repeated `my_array[my_array.length - 1]`, kind of noising

Comment: splice() work for you?, with a negative index i.e. my_array.splice(-1,1,sth)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to change array prototype, and use it like below:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];

Array.prototype.last=function() {
    if(this.length >= 1) {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};

arr.last();
```

Shuold work - you can check it in Chrome JS console.

Comment: Yeah - I think it's best way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Another fun trick would be to use `var ref = Array.prototype.last.bind(arr)`, to bind the function to an instance, so you don't have to pass around the array, just a bound function that returns the last item of desired array.